# Model is null even it's is passed in MVC 5 view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get multi url path images from database

I tried to write this code in controller

```
NourEntities3 db = new NourEntities3();           
    public List<Image> img;            

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
            var images = db.Images.ToList();
             img = images;
            return View(img);

    }
    public FileStreamResult GetImage(string filename)
    {
        string fn = Server.MapPath(filename);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fn))
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fn));
            return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fn)));
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and my view Looks Like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<nouur.Models.Image>
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}
  @foreach (var item in Model){
<div class="portfolio-item set-bg fw19" data-setbg="@Url.Action("GetImage","Retrieve",new{ filename=item.ImagePath })">
<a href="@Url.Action("GetImage","Retrieve",new{ filename=item.ImagePath })" class="portfolio-view">loadmore</a>
</div>}
```

My model :

```
  public partial class Image  
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Upload File")]
    public string ImagePath { get; set;} 
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
}
```

I excpected to get path from database .....but it appears error says that

> model is null

and

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

Comment: exactly which line throws the error? have you stepped through the controller and view code using the Visual Studio debugger to look at the flow of the code, and what the variable values are at each step, and try and determine where things start to go wrong?

Comment: this line   @foreach (var item in Model)

Comment: yes I did it always show me an error in model and says it equal null

Comment: and what about in the controller? Does it run the database code and populate the list? or does something go wrong? If you pause on the line `return View(img);` does `img` contain anything? What about the previous lines? That's what I mean by stepping through the code. Work backwards from the problem line until you start to notice it doesn't do what you expected.

Comment: sorry for late ...  am sorry am new in mvc

Comment: when i do a mark in the line you said it doesn't arrive ... it makes error before arrive

Comment: So try an earlier line, until you find the source of the issue. What exactly is the error, by the way?

Comment: the error in model....it  can't get path images from database

Comment: Does the line `var images = db.Images.ToList();` work? Do you get a valid list in `images`, with all the right fields populated in each object?